# Ter "êxito" ou ter "sucesso"? (Success translation) European portuguese

Tags: tradução, português-europeu

As palavras *êxito* e *sucesso* podem ser usadas com o mesmo significado?

Exemplos:

> 1. Your name was successfully added → O teu nome foi adicionado com êxito/sucesso
> 2. We are committed to your success → Estamos comprometidos com o teu êxito/sucesso

Qual palavra e mais comum no português europeu?

Comment: Tás a ver? Isto aqui é que é contexto! E arranjei-te uma seta bonita, mas se não gostares podes sempre reeditar e voltar ao que lá tinhas.

Comment: jajajaja obrigado. Faço o melhor que posso. Alguma resposta? :)

Comment: Há de aparecer uma resposta ou duas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há grande diferença, ambas as palavras podem ser usadas para descrever um resultado positivo. Eu faria contudo algumas alterações:

> O teu nome foi adicionado com êxito/sucesso.

Aqui, *com êxito/sucesso* é redundante; um nome não pode ser "adicionado sem êxito". Preferiria: *a adição do nome foi bem-sucedida* ou *executada com sucesso*.

> Estamos comprometidos com o teu êxito/sucesso.

*Comprometido* é aqui ambíguo, e pode significar "exposto a perigo" (estamos dependentes de que tenhas sucesso). Por isso eu preferiria:

> Estamos empenhados no teu êxito/sucesso.

Comment: Adorei a resposta, obrigado.